# Apache redirect without querystring?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my apache rewriterule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cate_id\=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^cate.php$ category-%1-b0.html [R=301,L]
```

And I want to redirect **cate.php?cate_id=72** to **category-72-b0.html**, but it redirect to **category-72-b0.html?cate_2=72**, I don't want the querystring after **.html**, is there anyway to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^cate.php/.*$ category-%1-b0.html? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Notice the "?" at the end of the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cate_id\=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^cate.php$ category-%1-b0.html? [R=301,L]
```